# Newly created folders not copied to destination using robocopy

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

A Job copies files from one server(X) to other server(Y).
We have a batch job scheduled in destination server that copies files from server(Y) to server(Z). The newly copied folders(for the first time) in the Y server on the same day the batch file runs is not copied to Z server.

Command Line used is

```
robocopy /ZB /R:3 /W:2 /s /e "\\Sourceserver\Data" "E:\Data" /np /move /log+:Logfile.txt
```

The last modified date of the new folder is greater than the Job start timestamp.
Ex: Job starts daily on 1:00 PM at destination server the timestamp of new folder in source is 1:01 PM or >1:01PM.

Please suggest  why the folder is not getting copied. The o/p is similar to image attached.Folder-->Subfolder & XML file.

Contents in folders:
[image: Contents in folders]

Contents of `E:\Data` :
[image: Contents of E:\Data]

Comment: What is the visible output from `robocopy /ZB /R:3 /W:2 /s /e "\\Source" "Destination" /np /move /L`?

Comment: All the folders and files are copied except the newly created folder. But when the job runs next day the new folders are been copied. I have a doubt if a folder is created after the job starts in destination, will it be copied or not?

Comment: @MC ND: the folders are not available in the target. The folders are copied when the job runs next day

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "newly created folders" also note that there is no need to use both **`/s`** and **`/e`**, just use the latter.

Comment: I have edited my question. We have three servers X, Y and Z. Y and Z are in our scope. The files  are not copied to Z when job runs first time after the folder been copied to Y. They will be copied when the job runs next day. I am not sure why the files newly copied are skipped for first time. Please suggest.